# Do I have a dead NIC?

Tags: linux, centos, kernel-modules, ethernet

OK so this is kind of a long one due to command output. Not necessarily in complexity as I'm only showing some basic t-shooting so any feedback would be appreciated.

Basically, I have a fairly new APU1D4 at home which I use for Snort IDS/IPS and network monitoring purposes. I PXE installed CentOS 7 onto it on the 01/03 (dd/mm - I'm in UK) and from this date up to the 09/03 (the last time I played with it) the system was fine. From the 09/03 - 13/03 I had been very busy at work so hadn't touched it. Today I've had some downtime and so I've been back on it. I am encountering problems with one of the GigE ports which I was not present before.

(Note: CentOS 7 renames eth0/1/2 to enp1s0/enp2s0/enp3s0.)

I am getting the following messages at both the terminal and in `/var/log/messages` at regular intervals:

```
Mar 15 10:45:50 vimto kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: rtl_phyar_cond == 1 (loop: 20, delay: 25).
Mar 15 10:45:50 vimto kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: rtl_phyar_cond == 1 (loop: 20, delay: 25).
Mar 15 10:45:50 vimto kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: rtl_phyar_cond == 1 (loop: 20, delay: 25).
```

There are no cronjobs to auto-update the system so I must assume that the r8169 driver had been in use from when I built the system on the 01/03. Here is the output from `lspci` about the three on board NICs:

```
# lspci -nn
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
```

And at further look:

```
# ethtool -i enp1s0
driver: r8169
version: 2.3LK-NAPI
firmware-version: rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no

[root@vimto ~]# ethtool -i enp2s0
driver: r8169
version: 2.3LK-NAPI
firmware-version: rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw
bus-info: 0000:02:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no

[root@vimto ~]# ethtool -i enp3s0
driver: r8169
version: 2.3LK-NAPI
firmware-version:
bus-info: 0000:03:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

When it comes to t-shooting any further than this I'm not totally clued up on what I am doing, but judging by the above output from ethtool the firmware isn't properly loaded for the NIC I'm having the problem with.

Perhaps this would also explain why the system is reporting the HWADDR incorrectly since `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp3s0` shows the correct HWADDR as `00:0D:B9:XX:XX:96` (the other two are the same except the decimal of the last octets are 94, 95). However the output of `ip addr` is reporting:

```
# ip addr
...
4: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:10:00:80:00:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

In fact the MAC address `00:10:00:80:00:10` returns as "Cable Television" according to here: http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/?string=00%3A10%3A00%3A80%3A00%3A10

The others report as I would expect as belonging to PC Engines (the APU manufacturer).

Any help greatly appreciated.

Note: despite being at work on the 13/03 I happen to know that there was a power cut at my home which did not get restored until around 09:15 that morning. However, all three NICs are connected to a Mikrotik router which isn't having any problems and neither are the other two NICs on the APU. Plus I have them powered into an APC SurgeArrest which I would think should provide some protection from these situations.

Comment: FWIW a MAC address isn't usually information you have to redact. By the time something like that is useful your network is probably already pretty well compromised. Redaction could cause confusing ambiguity.

Comment: Looking at the output of `modinfo` on the driver for the ethernet card it looks like there's a "debug" module option. You may trying setting that to `debug=8` or something and see if it produces more descriptive error messages in `/var/log/messages`

Comment: Also, what exactly is the issue you're concerned with? Is it just that error message? If so the debug information may tell you more. If it's that it's not getting an IP, it may just be that `HWADDR` has an incorrect value in it. You may try changing that to what it should be and seeing if that resolves the issue. If it reverts back some time later then that would likely be an issue with `NetworkManager`.

Comment: Consider running `mii-tool` and `ethtool` on the interfaces to see what they say. Don't ignore anything that they say that doesn't make sense: see if you can reconcile the apparent nonsense with reality.

Comment: @Bratchley - Yes, I wasn't clear about that: the problem is basically I cannot use the third NIC. It isn't obtaining an IP address, the HWADDR is incorrect and at regular intervals the string `enp3s0: rtl_phyar_cond == 1 (loop: 20, delay: 25)` is output at the terminal/stdout which is abnormal behaviour.

Comment: @BruceEdiger - mii-tool on enp3s0 gives `enp3s0: no link`. I don't know why I did not do this earlier but there are physically no LED-link lights illuminated on the APU for that NIC which I would think is telling. `mii-tool` is successfully restarting (`mii-tool -r`) the other NICs which output the negotiated link speed.

Comment: @unkle_junky - I'd say you might have a dead NIC.  If it's a PCI or PCIe card, re-seat it after cleaning contacts. Try a different cable - they go bad randomly. Try a different port on the router. If all that fails, you've got a dead NIC.

Comment: @BruceEdiger - NIC probably isn't the correct term, but rather GigE ports. They're soldered to the APU main-board.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with ThinkPad E540, ethernet didn't seem to work at all - no receive packets in ifocnfig, and all "TX" packets were accounted as dropped.

Solution is simple -- board somehow suspends the ethernet that doesn't have WakeOnLan turned on. This helped for me:

```
ethtool -s enp3s0 wol g
ifconfig enp3s0 down
ifconfig enp3s0 up
```

Comment: Could you clarify why if you changed it with ethtool, you need to down and up the interface?

Comment: No idea why it would be significant, but in my case it didn't work without down/up. Wild guess is that the adapter needed to reinitialize or something.

Comment: @exa : I tried it, but it hasn't worked. Was worth a go. I'm not convinced that the port has died. The board (APU1D4) is brand new and while I get electronics can sometimes just "die", I think statistically, it should be rare given the condition of the board when I purchased it (new).

Comment: Try again, I notoced that the solution also works for me just sometimes. Enabling wake on lan in BIOS helped.

Also, some people report success with realtek driver instead of kernel r8169. Didn't have time to check the difference.